# TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'ev.touches.length')

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

I have the following error

TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'ev.touches.length')
The line that generates this error is 289 on the jquery.hammer.js file:

```
// touch
else if(sourceEventType.match(/touch/)) {
     count_touches = ev.touches.length;
}
```

..

```
$('#detail').on('touchend', '.close', function (e) {
    $('.detail-overlay').trigger('touchend'); // Web inspector error starts here
});
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: It means that either "ev" is undefined, or that the object it references has no property "touches".

Comment: When an error points to a line in a library, it's more often than not a red herring, and there's a problem elsewhere with your code. Can you post a fiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: $('#detail').on('touchend', '.close', function (e) {
    $('.detail-overlay').trigger('touchend'); // Web inspector error starts here
});